# Не получается выполнить сортировку таблицы базы данных Room

Tags: android, kotlin, sqlite, android-room, android-sqlite

Dao:

```
@Dao
    interface ExchangeRateDao {
    
    ...
    
        @Query("SELECT * FROM exchange_rate_table ORDER BY name ASC")
        fun getSortCurrencyAlphabetAscending() : LiveData<List<ExchangeRateModel>>
    
    ...
    }
```

класс ExchangeRateDataSourceIMPL

```
class ExchangeRateDataSourceIMPL(private val dao: ExchangeRateDao) : ExchangeRateDataSource {

    ...

    override fun getSortCurrencyAlphabetAscending(): LiveData<List<ExchangeRateModel>> {
        return dao.getSortCurrencyAlphabetAscending()
    }


}
```

Repository:

```
class ExchangeRateRepository(private val exchangeRateApiDataSource: ApiDataSource,
                             private val exchangeRateDataSource: ExchangeRateDataSource,
                             private val dao: ExchangeRateDao
                             ) : ExchangeRateCall {

...

    override fun getSortCurrencyAlphabetAscending(): LiveData<List<ExchangeRateModel>> {
        return exchangeRateDataSource.getSortCurrencyAlphabetAscending()
    }

...

}
```

UseCase:

```
class ExchangeRateUseCase(private val exchangeRateCall : ExchangeRateCall) {

...

    fun getSortCurrencyAlphabetAscending() : LiveData<List<ExchangeRateModel>> {

        return exchangeRateCall.getSortCurrencyAlphabetAscending()

    }

...

}
```

ViewModel:

```
class ExchangeRateViewModel(private val exchangeRateUseCase: ExchangeRateUseCase) : ViewModel() {

...

    fun getSortCurrencyAlphabetAscending() = viewModelScope.launch {
        exchangeRateUseCase.getSortCurrencyAlphabetAscending()
    }

...

}
```

Обработка нажатия на кнопку сортировки во фрагменте:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_exchange_rate, container, false)

    initRecyclerExchangeRate()
    loadExchangeRate()

    binding?.sort?.setOnClickListener {
        exchangeRateViewModel?.getSortCurrencyAlphabetAscending()
        initRecyclerExchangeRate()
        loadExchangeRate()
    }

    return binding?.root
}
```

Comment: Так а проблема-то в чём?

Comment: @woesss, на кнопку нажимаю, строка `exchangeRateViewModel?.getSortCurrencyAlphabetAscending()` отрабатывает, но сортировка не происходит, таблица остаётся не отсортированной

Comment: У вас `getSortCurrencyAlphabetAscending()` возвращает `LiveData`, который вы игнорируете и новые данные теряются вместе с ним. И дальше вы вызываете тот же `loadExchangeRate()`, что и при старте фрагмента, который снова загружает несортированный список

Comment: @woesss, а как сделать по другому? (я просто ещё не очень разбираюсь)

Comment: @woesss, кажется я понял, что нужно добавить, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Изменения, после которых всё заработало:

ViewModel:

```
ExchangeRateViewModel(private val exchangeRateUseCase: ExchangeRateUseCase) : ViewModel() {
...

    val getSortCurrencyAlphabetAscending = exchangeRateUseCase.getSortCurrencyAlphabetAscending()

...
}
```

фрагмент:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_exchange_rate, container, false)

    initRecyclerExchangeRate()
    loadExchangeRate()

    binding?.sort?.setOnClickListener {

        exchangeRateViewModel?.getSortCurrencyAlphabetAscending?.observe(
            viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                exchangeRateAdapter?.setList(it)
                exchangeRateAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        )
    }

    return binding?.root
}
```